# How does .poll method works?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using .poll method in my application, I have alot of messages in my lag but on call of .poll why we return only few messages?. I only have one topic and 5 partitions as of now all the data goes to only one partition.

Spring-kafka 1.3.9 release
Kafka -> 1.0

Comment: can you show the code how you are doing it? and how many consumers do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase maximum records fetched by increasing `max.poll.records` which by default is 500. Use this config to limit total records returned from a single call to poll.

> all the data goes to only one partition

Well it depends on your key of message.

In case you are not providing any key, your message will be distributed randomly across partitions.

In case you are providing key, keys will be hashed and messages with the same key will go to the same partition.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

Comment: My max.poll.records  is set to 50,000 records. So I should get all the messages in lag right? But still when I do .poll I get only few random number of messages